# Riak failed to start within 15 seconds after renaming node

Tags: riak

sudo riak start does not work anymore after I change nodename from nodename=riak@127.0.0.1 to nodename=riak@192.x.x.x. I followed the steps mentioned here: https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/latest/using/cluster-operations/changing-cluster-info/index.html.
I am using Oracle VM, Ubuntu 18.04 , installed Riak 2.2.5.

The error is:
Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.

Riak console gives me a part not okay:
Root: /usr/lib/riak
Erlang R16B02_basho10 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]

[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed

Does someone have similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like some kind of config related issue. Did you follow all the re-ip steps to the letter? Is there any data on this node you need to keep? If not, probably the easiest way to fix this is to delete the ring directory or failing that, the entire data directory.

That said, before deleting stuff, you might want to check whether any Riak or beam processes (`ps aux | grep [b]eam` and `ps aux | grep [r]iak`) have been left running and kill those processes before trying to start again.

You may also wish to look at */var/log/riak/console.log* and share the contents of the entire last start up attempt in this question and future ones. Generally, the more relevant information you share, the easier it is for the community to help you.

`Erlang has closed` is usually sent after it told you what went wrong either in `riak console` or in the log files. Having all the things it told you before that point would also be beneficial to aid with diagnosis.

Speaking as the package manager for Riak, did you build this version of Riak yourself? Ubuntu 18 never had a 2.2.5 release. See https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.2/2.2.5/ubuntu/ and you'll notice there is no package for Bionic.
Version 2.2.5 had a tagging issue where two of different versions of dependencies had conflicting tags and when you built it, it could result in problems in the final build. To avoid this, 2.2.6 is the official first open source release and does have a Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) release at https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.2/2.2.6/ubuntu/ which you can find in the appropriate subfolder.

Given the potential risk of using 2.2.5 in production based on which versions of the dependencies that git chose to pull in at time of build, you may wish to consider taking this opportunity to update to 2.2.6 or 2.9.10 (https://files.tiot.jp/riak/kv/2.9/2.9.10/ubuntu/) as both can do in-situ upgrades from a 2.2.5 setup. The upgrade process would be to stop the node, optionally back up the data directory, install the new package, make any necessary changes to the config files and start the node again. The full process is documented at https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.9.0p5/setup/upgrading/version/ but if you are already running 2.2.5, many of the steps listed will not apply.

Comment: Yes. I followed the steps. I also deleted a ring every time when I changed the nodename. The /var/log/riak/console.log gives:                                                                        2021-12-17  <0.7.0> Application lager started on node 'riak@192.x.x.x' and similar stuff, but then I have this kinf of rows:

Comment: [info] <0.76.0> alarm_handler: {set,{{disk_almost_full,"/snap/gnome-characters/761"},[]}}
 [error] <0.302.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.302.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching proplists:get_value(cacertfile, undefined, undefined) line 225 in gen_server:init_it/6 line 328
 [error] <0.300.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.300.0> with 0 ....etc.
 [info] <0.167.0>@riak_core_app:stop:116 Stopped  application riak_core.

Comment: sudo riak console gives: config is OK
-config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2021.12.18.14.09.41.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2021.12.18.14.09.41.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2021.12.18.14.09.41.args
Exec:  /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/2.2.5/riak

Comment: Root: /usr/lib/riak
Erlang R16B02_basho10 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:3:3] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]

[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed

Comment: {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_api,{{function_clause,[{proplists,get_value,[cacertfile,undefined,undefined],[{file,\"proplists.erl\"},{line,225}]},{riak_api_ssl,options,0,[{file,\"src/riak_api_ssl.erl.......etc

Comment: Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_api,{{function_clause,[{proplists,get_value,[cacertfile,undefined,undefined],[{file,"proplists.erl"},{line,225}]},{ria

Comment: `no function clause matching proplists:get_value(cacertfile, undefined, undefined)` looks like you are trying to use the https listener but don't have a certificate configured. To fix this, either switch to the http listener (comment out the https one and uncomment the http one) or configure Riak with a valid certificate to use https. As this says it's causing a crash, that will probably kill the start up sequence dead in the water.